# Modifying a VB Code to cut and paste to another sheet

Tags: vba

I have the below VB that someone helped me with that works well except I now need to make an addition. As it stands the VB is looking at Column "C" and if it is blank it will cut "A" & "B" and paste it to another sheet.  What I want to do is also include "SHOT10","SHOT15" & "SHOT20" as well. Meaning if those are also found in Column "C" to be cut and paste to the other sheet as well.

CODE

```
Sub ClearRange3()

Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Absence Line").Select
' Find last row
myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


' Loop through range
For i = 2 To myLastRow
If Cells(i, "C").Value = "" Then
    With Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B"))
        .Copy
        find_last_record = Worksheets("Duplicates").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("Duplicates").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & i)
        .ClearContents
    End With
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You have tagged your question with vb.net, but the code you posted looks more like vba (Visual Basic for Applications) in Excel. Which language are you using? The answer to your question may be different depending on the language.

Comment: I am so sorry - it's actually vba and not VBA.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you, `Or` is your friend.

```
Sub ClearRange3()

    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Absence Line").Select
    ' Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


    ' Loop through range
    For i = 2 To myLastRow
    If Cells(i, "C").Value = "" Or Cells(i, "C").Value = "SHOT10" Or Cells(i, "C").Value = "SHOT15" Or Cells(i, "C").Value = "SHOT20" Then
        With Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B"))
            .Copy
            find_last_record = Worksheets("Duplicates").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Duplicates").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & i)
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeanno, I wasn't sure how the add the "Or" in there.  Thanks for your help.